# Setting color-words option by default on git-show

Tags: git

It's easy to configure git-diff to enable color-words by default.

How can I equally configure `git-show` to use `color-words` by default?

The only option I found so far was to use an alias:

```
[alias]
sh = show --color-words
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *[color "command"]*. Here is an example. You need to check what options "show" has.

```
[color "diff"]
    frag = cyan
    new = green
    commit = yellow
[color "branch"]
    current = green
[color "status"]
    updated = green
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Oleksandr. I could not find, however, any way to specify `word-diff`. I tried `[color "show"] word-diff = color` but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: @Wladston try "diff" and "status" - perhaps it is the same for git.

Comment: I've already got colored output for "diff" and "status". The `--color-words` option is already enabled by default for `diff`. The only thing that's missing is to find a way to make the option always enabled to "show". For reference, running `git config --global color.diff auto` makes it work for the `diff` commands by default.

Answer (score 1):

As you can't do this in gitconfig you can still wrap the git command in your ~/.zshrc

```
function do_git {
  cmd=$1
  shift
  extra=""
  if [ "$cmd" '==' "diff" ]; then
    extra="--color-words"
  fi
  "`whence -p git`" "$cmd" "$extra" "$@"
}
alias  git='do_git'
```

or in ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_rc

```
function do_git {
  cmd=$1
  shift
  extra=""
  if [ "$cmd" == "diff" ]; then
    extra="--color-words"
  fi
  "`which git`" "$cmd" "$extra" "$@"
}
alias  git='do_git'
```

Answer (score -1):

#### `--color-words`

Simply highlight word instead of lines when executing diff.

Here is a sample of the difference with and without the `--color-words`

[image]

---

> `color.diff.whitespace`
> git diff will use `color.diff.whitespace` to highlight them

---

#### Script (example)

```
#!/bin/sh
WS=$(git config --get-color color.diff.whitespace "blue reverse")
RESET=$(git config --get-color "" "reset")
echo "${WS}your whitespace color or blue reverse${RESET}"
```

---

If you want to color out other stuff you can as well.

```
[color]
  ui = auto
[color "branch"]
  current = yellow reverse
  local = yellow
  remote = green
[color "diff"]
  meta = yellow bold
  frag = magenta bold
  old = red bold
  new = green bold
[color "status"]
  added = yellow
  changed = green
  untracked = cyan
```

Comment: CodeWizard, thanks for answering! But like I clearly stated in the answer, I know how do make it work with git-diff. I want to make it work with git-show, **without** me having to type `color-words` manually each time--I want to find out how to configure that option as *default* for git.

Comment: And why not using the alias you have?

Comment: You can use scripts in alias as well and not just simple commands.

Comment: You know you also have `--color=always`

Comment: thanks! I just don't want to get used to typing my alias only to become frustrated when I try it in a computer that doesn't have my specific settings. As a reference, `git config --global color.diff auto` makes it for the `diff` commands. I wonder why it doesn't get applied to the `show` commands too…

Comment: There is not such a config for show. not as far a i know. you can see more about colors here: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html

Comment: it's there! Search that page for "word-diff" and "color-words".

Comment: I ment i dont thnk there is auto config not the values themself.